# Benchmarking HTTP server, reference tests

Tags: c#, http, benchmarking

I'm building a socket framework for .NET similar to Javas Netty. The reference implementation is a HTTP server which I would like to benchmark.

Are there any reference tests (tests for other web servers) which have defined the documents that should be served? Or do I have to test all servers by myself (to get a comparison)?

Answer (score 0):

I found this article which helps a lot: http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~kerneis/research/web-benchmark/

And I also found these tools: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking

Probably your socket server have much less overhead comparing to a HTTP server, so maybe it's not so interesting to make this comparison head to head.

Comment: This article is also useful: http://blog.std.in/2010/09/24/benchmarking-web-socket-servers/